# Boundedness in a space implies boundedness in the subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space. And let $A$ be an unbounded operator with the domain $D(A)$ which is densely continuously embedded into $X$.

Recall that if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm of $X$ then that of $D(A)$ is $\|x\|_{D(A)}=\|x\|+\|Ax\|$ for all $x\in D(A)$.

Now, let $U\subset D(A)$ be bounded in terms of $\|\cdot\|$. In other words, there exists $M>0$ such that $\|x\|\leq M$ for all $x\in U$.

Then, is it true that $U$ is bounded in terms of $\|\cdot\|_{D(A)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is unbounded then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $D(A)$ such that $\|x_n\| \to 0$ and $\|Ax_n\| \to \infty$. Take $U=\{x \in D(A):\|x\|\leq 1\}$. Clearly  $U$ is not bounded for $\|.\|_{D(A)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But making clear, the concept of unbounded operator is not equivalent with 'not bounded' operator. Unbounded operator can be bounded.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator

Comment: Sure. But to prove that your claim is  not true we only have to give one counter-example. I have taken an example where $A$ is truly unvbounded to show that $U$ need not be bounded w.r.t. $\|.\|_{D(A)}$.  It is also obvious that $U$ is bounded w.r.t. $\|.\|_{D(A)}$ if $A$ happens to be a bounded opeartor. @LevBahn

Comment: You are right! I think I misunderstood from the sentence 'If $A$ is unbounded...'.  I am not sure then the existence of $x_n$ such that  $\|x_n\|\rightarrow 0$ and $\|Ax_n\|$ is true..

Comment: If $A$ is not bounded, then for each $C_n>0$ there would exists $(x_n)$ such that $\|Ax_n\|>C_n\|x_n\|$.. but ... can we specify $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Take $C_n=n$ and consider $y_n=\frac {x_n} {\sqrt n \|x\|_n}$. Then $y_n \to 0$ and $\|Ay_n\| \to \infty$.  @LevBahn

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!